install4j-runtime 10.0.8 dependency is not downloading
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.install4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>install4j-runtime</artifactId>
           <version>10.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

We have got above artifact details from install4j API documentation. We have upgraded our version license from 7 to 10. Is it required to get jar version 10 or can we continue with older version?
We are getting "Missing artifact com.install4j:install4j-runtime:jar:10.0.8" with the shared artifact.

This dependency is available at
https://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository/com/install4j/install4j-runtime/10.0.8/
You have to define the repository
<repository>
   <id>ej-technologies</id>
   <url>https://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository</url>
</repository>

in order to download it.

It would be really great if you can upload the jar to Maven Central
